# Sitecore CMS Creating new user and role

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

Can anyone help me with issue I get when trying to sign up with new user created? 
It says: "You do not have access to the system. If you think this is wrong, please contact the system administrator."

I've created new role, added member to that role, double checked user's password and enabled user. I've also set the domain to sitecore.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your user should be a member of `Sitecore Client Authoring` role:

> **Sitecore Client Authoring**
>   Sitecore Client Authoring provides access
>   to basic item editing features and applications.

Either assign this role to your user or change your role to inherit from `Sitecore Client Authoring`.

More information can be found in [Sitecore Security Reference](https://www.sitecore.net/~/media/Products/Product%20Categories/Web%20Content%20Management/Enterprise%20Ready/Security/securityreference-usletter.ashx)

Comment: Is it mandatory that all user are has role or inherited from  "Sitecore client authoring". Can we create our own role like "Sitecore client authoring"?